# How to update file upladed to remote nexus by mistake

Tags: maven, nexus

I uploaded file using `mvn deploy:deploy-file` but I uploaded wrong file. How can I update or remove this file if I don't have direct access to nexus?

Comment: You dont have access to Nexus? You can delete it through the console, so you could ask someone who does have access. but TBH if you are uploading artifacts you should have access

Comment: I have access only through maven.

Comment: Someone will have access though...

Answer (score 0):

Ask your Nexus admin to delete it through the UI.

If this is a SNAPSHOT, you also have the option of deploying the same file using the same version number.  That way, when others reference 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT, they get the intended version.  And eventually the bad SNAPSHOT will probably get deleted through a scheduled job.  This is a decent workaround while you contact your Nexus administrator.